# Relation between P and FP

Tags: computational-complexity

For a decision problem that belongs to P can we assume that the equivalent function problem belongs to FP? For example: Is 8 a primal number? Belongs to P means that Find a primal number belongs to FP? My intuition says yes. Am I correct?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "the equivalent function problem" to a decision problem

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/). In any case, you first need to exactly say what you mean by "the equivalent function problem". Defining a search/function problem which would nicely corresponding to a decision problem is tricky.

Comment: A more "adaquate" version  of the PRIME problem would be “Given $n$ and $k$,  is $k$ a factor of $p$?” and the corresponding function problem would be "Given $n$ and $k$, find a non-trival factor of $p$ which is less than or equal to $k$"

Answer (score 3):

The example doesn't make sense, because "Find a primal number" is just a single question, not something that has instances.  The most obvious sense-making analog has an obvious negative answer.  For example: The problem (with input $m,n\in\mathbb N$) "Is $m!=n$?" is in P, but the problem (with input just $m$) "Find $m!$" is not in FP (because there isn't even enough time to write the answer).

Even if you insist on polynomial-sized answers (so that they could be written out in the available time), there would be examples like the following: The problem "Is $v$ a satisfying truth assignment for propositional formula $A$?" (with input $v$ and $A$) is in P, but "Find a satisfying truth assignment for $A$ (or determine that none exists)" won't be in FP unless P equals NP.

Comment: I get what you mean. Basically i wanted to ask this: We know that Factoring belongs in the intersection of NP with co-NP. Now if P is equal to the intersection of NP with co-NP, factoring belongs in FP or not? Isn' that contradictory with that you have answered me? Cause as you said I can find quickly if v satisfies A but i can not find one such v unless P=NP. Can you explain it a bit further to me?  

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Factoring belongs in the intersection of NP with co-NP"?  To me, factoring is a search problem ("On input n find the prime factorization of n") while NP and co-NP are classes of decision problems (problems with yes-or-no answers).

Comment: Yes, once again I didn't express myself correctly. Given some numbers I can tell if they are prime factors of n or not, which if I get it,implies that this problem belongs to NP intersected with co-NP. Now if suddenly someone had a proof that P = NP intersection co-NP would that imply that factoring (finding the primal factors not just checking a probable answer)belongs to FP or not?  

Comment: The problem of deciding whether some given numbers are prime factors of n is in P (because primality can be decided in PTime, and deciding whether they're factors is just a matter of dividing); so is deciding whether they're the full prime factorization of n (just multiply them together after checking that they're prime).  Despite all that, factorization is not known to be in P.

Comment: Every problem in P also belongs in the NP co-NP intersection.If P=NP intersection co-NP, then it would mean that testing the answer (NP) or the refutation of it (co-NP) is as easy as a P problem. Wouldnt that mean that I can compute a primal factorisation efficiently? Can you give me some conditions that would result in factorization being in FP? I really want to thank for the help and ask kindly if you can also give some guideline in another question I asked http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66272/can-i-achieve-something-better-with-the-probabilistic-turing-machine-in-matter-of

Comment: If I understand your last comment correctly, then I already answered it in my previous comment.  Testing a proposed prime factorization is easy; it's in P (regardless of whether all problems in NP intersect co-NP are in P --- this particular one is known to be in P).  But that does not make it easy to find prime factorizations; that problem is not known to be in FP.  

I therefore conjecture that I don't understand your last comment correctly; please clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

In motivating of some research areas, it is sometimes argued or implied that many important function problems are [self-reducible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_problem#Self-reducibility), and therefore equivalent to the corresponding decision problems.

This argument can be misunderstood to imply more than it does.

- Not every function problem is self-reducible, or at least not too obviously.
- The standard reduction in complexity research is the [many-one reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction), while the self-reducibility argument gives only a Turing reducibility.  Information-theoretically, this is quite natural, because when I'm decoding a mathematical object out of bits, I need many bits.  But this discrepancy basically kills most applications of the argument.

This question seems to attempt at reversing the argument, when asking about "the equivalent function problem".  This adds at least two more problems.

- There is a canonical decision problem corresponding to every function problem - namely "Does this potential solution work?"; but to my knowledge, there is no canonical function problem corresponding to each decision problem.
- Both the function problem and the decision problem must be defined as parametrized problems.  (Not "give me a prime number", but rather "give me a prime number `x` bits wide".)  There are many ways how to parametrize the problems and they are not all equivalent.

I think that an intriguing question was *attempted* here, but did not come anywhere close to being successfully *asked*.